# What's the best way to implement rubi in SVG

Tags: svg

While HTML5 has support for [ruby markup](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/ruby/markup.en.html) for quite a while now, I can't find any information about such a capability for SVG. Given that this feature is not supported, what would be the proper way to implement this functionality in SVG manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always use a `<foreignObject>` element to embed the text as HTML. However, I don't think this is supported by IE 11.

```html
<svg width="500" height="200" viewBox="0 0 500 200">
  <path d="M10 10H480V180H10Z" fill="#ccf" stroke="#99f" stroke-width="10"/>
  <foreignObject x="10" y="10" width="480" height="180">
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:50px; margin:30px 0 0 0; text-align:center;">ルビは<ruby><rb>簡単</rd><rt>かんたん</rt></ruby>です。</p>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! I only target Chrome at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

SVG is an XML compatible markup format for vector graphics. The canvas tag generally supports SVG, or at least a sub-set of it. But if you add your own tags, the browser won't recognise. The only way if to write a plugin or extension for a browser, which is likely beyond you capabilities.